# prevent Bootstrap Date Time Picker from hiding when you use the scrollbar in the document

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, scrollbar, datetimepicker

Sorry Guys - here is an example of the markup .
This then allows me to click the respective input and the date picker will show up.

how ever if I make ,my screen smaller the date picker is partially out of view. I want to allow the user to scroll with the scroll bar , how ever as soon as I click outside of the date picker it closes.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../ClientScripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js">    </script>

<!-- markup snippet -->

        <div class="planner-cell">
        <div class="inputgroup-container input-group planner-small-space-bottom editplan-input-big" id='Div6' data-bind="datetimepickerhandler: targetDate, datePattern: datePattern"> <%--data-bind="datetimepickerhandler: targetDate, datePattern: datePattern"--%>
            <input type='text' class="inputgroup-input pointerDefault" readonly="" />
            <span class="input-group-addon inputgroup-icon calendar-icon pointerHand"></span>
            <span class="inputgroup-icon cleardate-icon pointerHand"   id="clearTargetDateSubAction"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

inside the datepicker JS file I ahve commented out this :

```
   //if (!this.isInput) {
   //    $(document).on(
   //      'mousedown.datetimepicker' + this.id, $.proxy(this.hide, this));
   //}
```

to allow myslef to achieve the above mentioned. ther are however some flaws to do this .

I was wondering if there is a jquery way achive the same without diving into the JS file.

Comment: You are using both bootstrap-datepicker and bootstrap-datetimepicker.js, or only one of those?

Comment: You should show us some code that has the behavior that you are trying to change.